# Schedule task in Win7 should be event triggered by specific computer presence in network

Tags: networking, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, eventtrigger

**Hi good folks on Stackoverflow!**

I'm curious if it is possible to create an event based schedule task by a specific resolved host-name in a private network. The task scheduler in Windows 7 seems to be pretty good, but I got lost in all the possibilities, especially the event-base-trigger section.
So here's my task:

If a specific network connection via WLAN is established and a specific PC is online in my private network (from which I want data), it should start a program which synchronices me two folders (local and from the pc in network).

I actually don't want to program something new with java or something similiar if it is not absolutely necessary.
The synchronising part is not the problem. Afters hours of searching on various sites on the internet I still don't have a clue how to do the PC-online-in-network part. Is there a specific event-based-trigger I can use to look for a specific host-name? Has someone any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer but a hint.

You can create new tasks with right-click to computer and 'manage' (admin).
The image shows what I found where events can be used to trigger userdefined scripts.
Sadly I do not know which event can be used of if it is any event of the ones shown below.
Just so that you know. Maybe other people know.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! I found these sources of triggers, but as you mentioned it, it is not clear with which I'm able to get a specific hostname by filtering. However, thank you so far.

Comment: We will see, maybe some expert sees this and knows what to do.